# more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

All my SQLAlchemy models query just fine, but there is one that gives me:

```
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

This is the (shortened) SQL generated by SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT poi.key
,poi.pok
,poi.noc
,coalesce((
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN (sum(item.noc) IS NULL)
            THEN NULL
        ELSE :param_1
        END AS anon_1
    FROM item,poi
    WHERE poi.key = item.poi_key
    GROUP BY item.key
    ), poi.noc) AS coalesce_1
,coalesce((
    SELECT sum(soi.noc) AS sum_1
    FROM soi
    WHERE soi.poi_key = poi.key
        AND soi.is_shipped = 0
    ), :param_2) AS coalesce_2
,coalesce((
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN (sum(item.noc) IS NULL)
            THEN NULL
        ELSE :param_1
        END AS anon_1
    FROM item,poi
    WHERE poi.key = item.poi_key
    GROUP BY item.key
    ), poi.noc) - ee((
    SELECT sum(soi.noc) AS sum_1
    FROM soi
    WHERE soi.poi_key = poi.key
        AND soi.is_shipped = 0
    ), :param_2) AS anon_2
FROM poi
```

The model is:

```
class POI(Base):
    key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    pok = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    noc = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(pok,),
        ForeignKeyConstraint([pok],),{})
```

I'm using `scoped_session` since my application is multi-threaded and I thought that could be the problem. But it wasn't. I've tried every variation of using `Session`, but the problem persist. The strange thing is that upon application initialization, when multiple threads are started that fetch data from the db, only this query throws the error. Invoking only this query (manually) works fine somehow. So the problem is apparently in interaction with other queries.

The error is a bit vague to me, but I think the problem is that a subquery should return one result, not many. I'm at a loss where to start looking for the answer. Is it a threading issue? A Session issue? Something else?

Comment: `my application is multi-threaded and I ...` The behaviour should *not* depend on the threadedness. If it does ... If it doesn't ...

Comment: It seems to me that sqlalchemy should be using joins instead of subselects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need `FROM item,poi` in 2 subqueries and I also remove the `group by` in those too. Regading the case expression involving :param_1 I am not sure if what I suggest below is funcionally correct or not, but you need to create a SUM() value before you can test if that SUM() IS NULL.

```
SELECT
      poi.key
    , poi.pok
    , poi.noc
    , COALESCE((
            SELECT SUM(COALESCE(item.noc,:param_1))
            FROM item
            WHERE poi.key = item.poi_key
      )
      , poi.noc) AS coalesce_1
    , COALESCE((
            SELECT
                  SUM(soi.noc) AS sum_1
            FROM soi
            WHERE soi.poi_key = poi.key
                  AND soi.is_shipped = 0
      )
      , @param_2) AS coalesce_2
    , COALESCE((
            SELECT SUM(COALESCE(item.noc,:param_1))
            FROM item
            WHERE poi.key = item.poi_key
      )
      , poi.noc) - ee((
            SELECT
                  SUM(soi.noc) AS sum_1
            FROM soi
            WHERE soi.poi_key = poi.key
                  AND soi.is_shipped = 0
      )
      , :param_2) AS anon_2
FROM poi
```